# Proper initialization of lists in python

Tags: python

I am trying to implement [text justification algorithm](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/fall09/lecture_notes/lecture20.pdf)

```
    def line_cost(words, max_width):
        """
           words are list of words (strings) to be justified
        """
        if not words:
            return 0
        if not words_fit(words, max_width):
            return float('+Inf')
        return extra_spaces_for_line(words, max_width)**3

    def words_fit(words, max_width):
        return extra_spaces_for_line(words, max_width) > 0

    def extra_spaces_for_line(words, max_width):
        return max_width - len(" ".join(words))

    def cost_words_itoj_in_line(i, j, words, max_width):
        tentative = line_cost(words[i:j], max_width)
        if tentative < float('+Inf') and j == len(words):
            return 0
        return tentative

    def cost_lines(words, max_width):
        cost_itoj = [[float('+Inf')] * (len(words) + 1)] * (len(words) + 1)
        for i in range(len(words) + 1):
            for j in range(i, len(words) + 1):
                cost_itoj[i][j] = cost_words_itoj_in_line(
                    i, j, words, max_width)
                # print(cost_itoj[i][j]) # If I uncomment this line, I see the value of cost_itoj just fine, most of them non-zero.
        return cost_itoj
```

With this definition, when I call:

```
>>> words = "Never forget what you are, for surely the world will not. Make it your strength. Then it can never be your weakness. Armour yourself in it, and it will never be used to hurt you.".split()
>>> cost_lines(words, 15)
```

I get all list of lists filled with zeros.

Consider another version of cost_lines function:

```
def cost_lines(words, max_width):
            cost_itoj = [[float('+Inf')] * (len(words) + 1)] * (len(words) + 1)
            for i in range(len(words) + 1):
                for j in range(i, len(words) + 1):
                    yield cost_words_itoj_in_line(
                        i, j, words, max_width)
```

With this definition, however, when I call

```
>>> list(cost_lines(words, 15))
```

I get a list of lists filled with proper values of cost. What am I doing wrong in terms of scoping or initialization of `cost_itoj` variable in the first definition of `cost_lines`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scoping has nothing to do with this: you are simply failing to initialize your data structure correctly.  `cost_itoj = [[float('+Inf')] * (len(words) + 1)] * (len(words) + 1)` creates a list of `Inf`s, and then creates a list with multiple references to that ONE inner list, rather that a 2-dimensional array as you presumably intended.  In other words, `cost_itoj[1][x]` refers to the same list element as `cost_itoj[2][x]`.  You're calculating all the right values, but each row overwrites the last row's results; I guess your final row was all zeros.

A proper initialization for a 2D array would look like this:

```
cost_itoj = [[float('Inf')] * (len(words)+1) for _ in range(len(words)+1)]
```

where `_` is a dummy variable needed for the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Would you recommend a reading on such referencing rules in Python?
Given your answer, another way to initialize 2D array is:
`[[float('+Inf') for _ in range(len(words) + 1)] for _ in range(len(words) + 1)] `

Which way is recommended Python style?